# Geometry nodes, how can I select one random polygon per island?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

how can I select one or more random polygons per island?

(one polygon per island )
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *accumulate field* node.

- use the islands index (*mesh island* node) into the group ID (set node to *face*)
- also use the islands index for the *ID* of a random value node (set to *Integer*)
- use the total output as the max of the random value node. (and 1 as the min)
- compare the *leading* output (of the *accumulated field* node) with the output of the random value node. set the compare to *equal*.

this will give you one random selection per mesh island.

[image]

Comment: thank u, why in accumulate field node, the value is 1 also in the random value node, the minimum is 1 ?

Comment: You are basically making an index per island and the total points. the trailing gives you an index starting from 0, and leading gives you an index starting from 1. The random value has to be in the range of the index (we generated). so if the range of the random value would be from 0, then it would have to go till one less then the *total* and be compared with trailing. granted this will only be one more node (subtract 1 from the total) I thought this was simpler (why add an extra node).